# How to correctly configure path for the Realm DB-file (<db_name>.realm) in iOS project?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, realm

Sorry for my english.

I have developed a mobile application that needs its own local data store. I chose Realm as the database management system. In the process of studying the Realm documentation I had no problems with the database design, it's normalization, the CRUD-operations and everything that is related directly to the code.

I was confused following. I test my application in the simulator. I did not create the local database. I’ve just done it as it is written in the documentation of Realm. Realm created by itself its database and I did not specify any settings. The location of my file with database is given below:
/Users/macbookpro/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices//EFECD945-285C-494F-8C1B-950D9AA05147/data/Containers/Data/Application/8D71FF0A-60D2-4875-96BB-36955E80D505/Documents/default.realm.

I quite inconvenient to apply each time this path for the analyzing of records in the database. The file is stored at this path is inaccessible for Realm Browser, because I need root privileges. I have seen that people store their .realm-files in project directory. Answer me please - how can I do it? Would it be the right alternative?

I have repeatedly seen the code, where paths to the database file appeared. For example, here: https://github.com/pietbrauer/CarthageRealmUploadFailureExample/blob/master/Carthage.checkout/realm-cocoa/examples/ios/swift/Migration/AppDelegate.swift
I'm not sure if it's the right direction.

As a result, I want to:

1) have on hand a database file and be able to quickly refer to it;

2) know the algorithm - how to set own path to the Realm-database
    file;

3) know what realm configuration must be on a real device, to
    ensure security and data integrity.

Thank you very much to all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you don't specify a path for the default Realm in your app, Realm will automatically create one named `default.realm` in the Documents directory of your app. On apps running in the iOS Simulator, this will save the Realm file in the appropriate Simulator folder, but you are correct in that it's not very intuitive to find it.

In response to your questions:

1. There is a cool utility called [SimPholders](http://simpholders.com) that lets you inspect the Documents folders of apps in the iOS Simulator. This is the best way to get at any Realm files the Simulator has generated very quickly.
2. When creating an instance of a `Realm` object, you can supply a `Configuration` object to customise it. You can explicitly set the file path of the Realm file by setting the `path` property of that `Configuration` object.
3. iOS supplies an automatic layer of file encryption on disk, that makes files unable to be read when the device is locked. If you want additional security, then it's possible to set the `encryptionKey` property of a Realm `Configuration` object to have a Realm itself encrypt that Realm file on disk.

I hope that helped! Let me know if you need any more clarification!

Comment: Tim, thank you very much!
My omission is that I did not read the documentation before the end of. But I advise nevertheless put <Realms> section (The Deafault Realm, Realm Configuration, ...) in the beginning, before the Models. This is initial setup - once and for all, a rather important point. Because it is much more logical. In my situation, I had to quickly implement a local store in the app. And I'm simply not reached the section where it is written. There is impossible for a newcomer to know about the content of the section on its headline - <Realms>.
In the rest - everything just great!

Answer (score 0):

1) and 2) does have very small effect on security and data integrity
3) if you are worry about security of you data, use Realm-level encryption like [here](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/tree/master/examples/ios/swift-2.1.1/Encryption)