# about Realm DataBaseFile and ios Library folder

Tags: ios, save, realm, documents, realm-mobile-platform

Can I store Realm database files and user pictures with personal information in the Library instead of the Documents folder?

When you want to back up your personal data, you can copy and move the Documents folder so that the user can access iTunes file sharing

I want to be able to backup directly.

Likewise, when you import it, you want to copy the folder from Documets back to the Libary folder to perform a backup restore function.

I am wondering if I saved the database file or user's personal information in the Library folder.

**If I store the realm's database files in the ios Library folder, Will it be Reject?**

Comment: This was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35883981/how-to-correctly-configure-path-for-the-realm-db-file-db-name-realm-in-ios-p

Comment: no i want to know If I store the realm's database files in the ios Library folder, Will it be Reject?