# Setting location of Realm in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, realm, nsfilemanager

I have read the Realm docs and used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35883981/how-to-correctly-configure-path-for-the-realm-db-file-db-name-realm-in-ios-p)  to try and set the location of Realm to the Application Support folder rather than the Documents folder.

My app requires an export of a file from the Documents folder so I can't users see the realm stuff in there too.

I'm using this code :

```
var config = Realm.Configuration()

    config.fileURL = (FileManager.default.urls(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first)

    // set the location
    Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config
    print (Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!)
```

... in an attempt to place realm and all its files etc in the applicationSupportDirectory But it's not working at all, other than when I print out the location it appends the application support bit at the end of the location like this...

```
.../Application/964D53C2-C880-4144-B5F0-688213820A67/Library/Application%20Support
```

Which is useless.

I've tried looking for a simple guide on how to actually specify the location of realm in Swift 4 but can't find anything other than the answer I've listed. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> try this code tested & working. we need to create Application Support directory it's not created by default.

```
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    var config = Realm.Configuration()

    let urls = fileManager.urls(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)

    if let applicationSupportURL = urls.last {
        do {
            try fileManager.createDirectory(at: applicationSupportURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
            config.fileURL = applicationSupportURL.appendingPathComponent("demo.realm")
        } catch let err {
            print(err)

        }
    }

    // Set this as the configuration used for the default Realm
    Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config

    print (Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!)
```

Comment: this is still creating a random file in the Docs directory - i've got another question for that problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56825173/how-to-stop-realm-creating-files-in-documents-folder

Comment: When you did this, did it also create a file in the docs directory?

Comment: No for me nothing is create in document directory everything in application support folder

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're passing it a url to a directory but it seems to be expecting a url to a file. Based on the [docs](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#configuring-a-realm) you should be able to do this.

```
config.fileURL = FileManager.default
    .urls(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    .first
    .appendingPathComponent("default.realm")
```

Comment: hey thanks for helping - unfortunately this requires .first to be unwrapped and also is causing Xcode and simulator to crash on launching!

Answer (score 0):

My version

```
// File Manager
let fileManager = FileManager.default

do {
    // Document directory URL
    let documentsDirectory = try fileManager.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
    
    // Create App folder
    try fileManager.createDirectory(at: documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("app.folder/"), withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)

} catch {
    print("Catch error")
}

// Configuring a Local Realm
var config = Realm.Configuration()

// Use the default directory, but add the app folder with the default realm file
config.fileURL = config.fileURL?.deletingLastPathComponent().appendingPathComponent("app.folder/default.realm")

// Set this as the configuration used for the default Realm
Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config

// Now print default Realm data base url
print(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!)
```